# Create JSON object from HTML elements (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, local-storage

Is there any way to get object **formated** like this from **html** via button click?

```
var Movie = [{id:"tt3783958", title:"La La Land", type:"Comedy, Drama, Music", year:"2016"}];
```

And then whit next button click, to append next object like this?

```
var Movie = [ {id:"tt3783958", title:"La La Land", type:"Comedy, Drama, Music", year:"2016"}, {id:"tt0488120", title:"Fracture", type:"Crime, Drama, Mystery", year:"2007"} ];
```

> **Live Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/q94eemn8/1/

Comment: What object do you want to make?

Comment: I want to make object like var Movie, just from button click "Add"

Comment: That object already exists in `Output`, so that does not make much sense. What do you want to have happen when you click the button?

Comment: Or are you trying to collect the details from the table row and append them into an existing object?

Comment: Exacly, I want to collect the details from table row and append them to existing object.

Comment: var Movie is just example, how it should look like, when details are collected from table row and appended into object. But I have no clue how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way you can do something like this. It's not entirely clear what you're looking to accomplish, so I took some guesses.

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/tre7dx8a/

Added `add` as a class for each button in HTML.

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  var Movies = [];
  $(".btn.btn-outline-success").click(function(e) {
    if ($(this).hasClass("add")) {
      var row = $(this).closest("tr");
      var movie = {};
      movie.id = row.find("td:eq(0)").html();
      movie.title = row.find("td:eq(1)").html();
      movie.year = row.find("td:eq(2)").html();
      movie.type = row.find("td:eq(3)").html();
      Movies.push(movie);
      console.log("Added Movie:", movie);
      $(this).html("Remove").toggleClass("add remove");
    } else {
      var id = $(this).closest("tr").find("td:eq(0)").html();
      var index = -1;
      $.each(Movies, function(k, v) {
        if (v.id == id) {
          index = k;
        }
      });
      if (index > -1) {
        Movies.splice(index, 1);
        console.log("Removed Movie:", id);
        $(this).html("Add").toggleClass("add remove");
      }
    }
  });
});
```

When `Add` is clicked, a `movie` object is created and populated with the items from the `<td>` in that `<tr>`. I used the `:eq()` selector to specifically identify each element. I then used `.html()` to read the content of the element. I could have also used `.text()`.

I then considered that the user may make a mistake or change their mind, so I set the button to toggle itself to a `Remove`. This has a similar action, but will find and remove the `movie` from the storage array.

You can move them to local storage in a similar manner. Might be worthwhile writing a function to send the data back and forth to/from local storage.

Comment: Exacly what I was looking for!